# Is there any way to get refresh and id tokens for Azure AD app via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am trying to find a way to get both refresh token and id token for an Azure AD app via PowerShell.

To get access token, I found this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azaccesstoken?view=azps-8.0.0) that suggests to use `Get-AzAccessToken`.

By using that command, I'm able to get the access token successfully. But I can't find any docs that gives command to get refresh and id tokens.

Am I making any sense? Is there any command that I can use in PowerShell to get refresh and id tokens for my Azure AD registered application?

Can anyone help me out with an workaround if possible?

Comment: As far as I know you can only do this by writing your own implementation. I'd suggest looking through the documentation of the MSAL .Net library (I always use that one or in some cases where I can't use an external library I just create the webrequest to get a token from the Microsoft token endpoint)

Comment: With the MSAL.PS module ( https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS) in PowerShell you're able to retrieve both `Access` and `ID` tokens. `RefreshTokens` however are cached automatically by the underlying `MSAL .Net` library, and a new access token retrieved using the `-Silent` option